# onPropertiesReady Event

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the viewer on an Angular app. I want to `console.log` the properties of the selected object.

Reading through the documentation, I found the [`getProperties`](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) function. The documentation says it raises a `onPropertiesReady` event, however I can't find it on the EVENTS section of the documentation. Am I missing something here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you need to wait for to make sure the properties have been loaded is `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT`. Take a look at this article: [Event Watcher](http://autode.sk/2yPetrP)

To listen for user selection, you need to use `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` which returns an array of dbIds in the arguments that you can pass to `viewer.getProperties(dbId, callback)`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed.