# How to write Javascript code for model browser while using autodesk-forge-viewer API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to replicate a part of demo shown [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=58c7ae474c6d400bfa5aaf37&_ga=2.233377754.510400454.1509359479-194568957.1507793733) using autodesk-forge-viewer api. Particularly, I am not able to find code snippet around how can I do navigation for a particular area of 3D model. For example, if render 3D model is house, I require that If a click on "Bed Room" which is a link somewhere in browser, 3D rendered model should show me that "Bed Room". In sample app shown, they are providing the same as a feature of "Model Browser".

Could anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to know the dbId's of the nodes you are interested in, most viewer API methods take dbIds as input. You get those either by listening to selection events, see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905672/onpropertiesready-event/46906578?noredirect=1#comment80760961_46906578), or by [parsing the instance tree](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/03/breaking-change-in-accessing-model-instance-tree-with-view-data-api.html) and checking the properties of the nodes to see if those are the ones you looking for.

You can then use methods such as `viewer.fitToView([dbIds])`, `viewer.hide([dbIds])`, `viewer.show([dbIds])` ... Here is another article that might be useful: [Hidding completely viewer nodes (no ghosting)](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hidding-completely-viewer-nodes-no-ghosting).

Hope that helps.